# Postgres drop constraints for a table using wildcards

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to drop constrains using wildcards `name_*` such that it drops all those that starts with name have regardless endings?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a wildcard in `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT`
However, you can do something like given below:

```
DO $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r in  SELECT
                conrelid::regclass,
                conname
            FROM
                pg_constraint
            WHERE
                contype IN ('f', 'p', 'u', 'c')
                AND connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
                AND conname ~* '^test*'
  LOOP
     EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE % DROP CONSTRAINT %',r.conrelid, r.conname;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the query...  I know the table name,  a little bit of the type of uniqueness constraint name I am looking for... I cannot use any of those information? @VibhorKumar

Comment: The query is very straight forward. It's selecting `conrelid` and `conname` (which is constraint name) from `pg_constraint` table. Below is the link of pg_constraint table definition:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html

Comment: `AND conname ~* '^test*'` condition make the list the select return empty?

Comment: I get an error  `ERROR:  query "SELECT 'ALTER TABLE % DROP CONSTRAINT %',r.conrelid, r.conname" returned 3 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 14 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601`